# How to use ajax in JSF inputtextbox to update h:selectOneRadio?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I was usinig JSF 2.0, richfaces, and a4j in my development. I have a radio button group that consist of 3 radio button, and there is a inputtextbox next to each of the radio button, just like the layout shown below:

```
radio button A | input textbox A
radio button B | input textbox B
radio button C | input textbox C
```

Whenever there is a focus on textbox, can this be done using ajax to update on radio button selection? E.g. when focus on input textbox B, then radio button B will be selected. May I know how this can be done?

Comment: Why ajax and not JavaScript (lighter and softer for client, easier to maintain for developers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to this, first using plain `javascript` and using `ajax` on `jsf` or `richfaces` components.
You can try using `a4j:ajax` nested inside your `h:inputText` and fire it whenever there is `focus` on your `textbox`.

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.value}" id="radio" />
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.textValue}" >
    <a4j:ajax event="onfocus" render="radio" action="{bean.setRadioSelected}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

On the action method set the value of selected radio to true.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The property action doesn't belong to a4j:ajax, I have to use listener. And I have changed the event onfocus to click because it is not supported by inputText. I have to wrapped the selectOneRadio with panelGroup because whenever the textbox is clicked, the radio control will disappear.

Comment: My bad, still confused from RF 3 to RF 4. Good thing you figured out. :)